# use Models in Cli in PhalconPHP

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

I just started out with Phalcon PHP and I have a question. I have a cli app running with the following code:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

...

// Load the configuration file (if any)
...

$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        __DIR__ . '/tasks',
        __DIR__ . '/models'
    ]
);
$loader->register();

$console = new ConsoleApp();
$console->setDI($di);

/**
 * Process the console arguments
 */
...

try {
    $console->handle($arguments);
} catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    ..
} catch (\Throwable $throwable) {
    ..
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    ..
}
```

And in the task I have `use Exchanges\Client as Exchanges;` and `$exchanges = Exchanges::findFirst(1);`

However it keeps returning `Class 'Exchanges\Client' not found` - how can I add it so this class actually is read?

As you can see I already tried loading in Models via the initial Cli class. The question is very much: How can I load a model into a task?

Comment: I know I use $loader->registerNamespaces...

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Comment: You are welcome!